# Why a 64bit executable is taking more time to complete when compiled with -mcmodel=large option with cc

Tags: gcc

Based upon the memory requirements I had to use `-mcmodel=large` option while compiling the c program. To my surprise the executable is taking more time to complete.

I donot understand why this is happening? How to check this issue.
Is it because of page faults?

Comment: On which computer (processor, memory), with which operating system? What compiler and version, and what optimization options? How did you benchmark? Please **edit your question** to improve it a lot

Comment: I am using gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 on Linux Mint 18 Sarah 64-bit with Kernel Linux 4.4.0-21-generic x86_64 and processor is Intel® Core™ i5-3450 CPU @ 3.10GHz × 4

Comment: Please *edit your question* but don't comment it